# Why a UILabel at Y position of 0 does not sit at top of screen

Tags: ios, uiview, uilabel

**Context**

- This is a `UIViewController` which is within a `UINavigationController` stack
- Within this `UIViewController` I'm adding a `UILabel` programmatically at (x,y) coordinates of (0,0)
- I've experimented adding `UILabel` to self.view (this is within a UIViewController) or adding `UILabel` to a `UIView`, this `UIView` is self.containerView

`self.containerView` is created and added to the view through this code:

```
- (void)addContainerView
{
    // Create a UIView with same frame as the screen bounds
    CGRect containerViewFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    self.containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:containerViewFrame];

    // Give the UIView a red background
    self.containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    // Add the view
    [self.view addSubview:self.containerView];
}
```

The `UILabel` is added through this code:

```
- (void)addTestLabel
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    label.text = @"this is a test";
    [self.view addSubview:label]; // OR [self.containerView addSubview:label]
}
```

[image]

When `UILabel` is added to `self.view`

[image]

When `UILabel` is added to `self.containerView`

**Questions**

- Why doesn't the `UILabel` sit right at the top of the screen, even behind the status bar?
- Why is there a difference between the `yPos`, dependent on whether it is added to `self.view` or `self.containerView`

Comment: This is an iOS 7 specific question. Since iOS 7 is under NDA, please demonstrate this problem with iOS 6 (where I don't believe you'll see quite the same issue), or ask your question on the dev forums.

Comment: The `y=0` position of `self.view` or `self.containerView` is relative to the view, and not the screen.

Comment: @RobNapier I built it in iOS6 and was able to replicate. I believe the main issue was the height of the UILabel. Although I'm still not 100% sure on why there is a difference between self.containerView and self.view

Comment: @drc: Its due to the height of the label. The label's origin point is still (0,0). If you reduce the height of the label you can see the difference. Or simply set a background colour for your label. You can see the frame of the label.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the background color of the label and I think you'll see what's going on.  The height of the label is 100 pixels and it's vertically centering it within that space.  Change the height to 20 or 30 and try it again.